# How do I set permissions on files in an unpacked Eclipse Plugin (not a jar)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, permissions

I have created an Eclipse feature set, composed of various plugins. One of these plugins contains an executable file that gets called from the plugin. The feature.xml file sets unpack="true" for this plugin, so it is installed as a directory rather than a jar.

But when Eclipse tries to launch the executable, it throws a "permission denied" error. Running chmod on the exectuable fixes this ... but I need this to happen automatically when people install the Eclipse plugin.

I've ensured that the executable file has the correct permissions before I build the plugin.

I'm thinking maybe there's a way to add installation tasks to a feature.xml, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, p2 TouchPoint instructions enable the execution of commands during the installation of a plugin.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Engine/Touchpoint_Instructions_35